# complicate sql join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to combine 2 tables and display a table.

I already did it in PHP, but I want to do it in SQL itself.

**Table 1:venki**

```
code  subject
10    english
11    tamil
12    history
```

**Table 2:venki2**

```
num opt1 opt2 opt3 allot 
f41  12    11   10   12
```

I need to display a table with columns of `num.venki2`, `opt1`, `opt2`, `opt3`, `allot` (5 columns). For the last 4 column values must be taken from table 1, for example: f41 , history. tamil, english, history.

Comment: Joining tables need some reference key so whats your reference key between 2 tables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.num 
      ,J1.[Subject] AS Opt1
      ,J2.[Subject] AS Opt2
      ,J3.[Subject] AS Opt3
      ,J4.[Subject] AS allot
FROM venki2 t2 LEFT JOIN venki J1
ON t2.opt1 = J1.Code
LEFT JOIN venki J2
ON t2.opt2 = J2.Code
LEFT JOIN venki J3
ON t2.opt3 = J3.Code
LEFT JOIN venki J4
ON t2.allot = J4.Code
```

Use Square brackets around Subject as it is a `key word` in sql server.

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/813d2/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
select venky2.num, TBLOPT1.[subject], 
TBLOPT2.[subject], TBLOP3.[subject], 
TBLALLOT.[subject]  
from venky2, venky as TBLOPT1, venky as TBLOPT2, venky as TBLOP3, venky as TBLALLOT
left join TBLOPT1 on venky2.opt1=TBLOPT1.code
left join TBLOPT2 on venky.opt2=TBLOPT2.code
left join TBLOP3 on venky2.opt3=TBLOP3.code
left join TBLALLOT on venky2.allot=TBLALLOT.code
```

Comment: error in your code - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'. - left join venky on venky2.opt1=venky.code as TBLOPT1

Comment: You need to alias table when JOINING tables not in `ON` clause.

Comment: sorry if I've written a mistaken code, I've edited it, a late edit but just for sake of correctness